# Incorrect id returned on LEFT JOIN in Mysql statement

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to get the id and timestamps of table `sellers` and all other columns (without knowing the column names) from these results returned from this MySql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sellers a 
LEFT JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN country_types c ON a.country_type_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN language_types d ON a.language_type_id = d.id 
WHERE a.email=?
```

The seller id though is incorrectly set because users, country_types, and language_types all have a value `id`.  How can I set seller_id and seller_timestamp?  I tried this but it is incorrect:

```
SELECT a.id seller_id, a.timestamp seller_timestamp, * FROM sellers a ...
```

Comment: Its not so clear what do you want. Although i think you want something like this: `SELECT a.id as seller_id, a.timestamp as seller_timestamp, b.*, c.*, d.* FROM sellers a .....`

Comment: I'd like all rows in tables a and those joined in b, c, and d.  In table a, I would like to give `id` and `timestamp` an alias to seller_id and seller_timestamp.

Comment: Ok, this above will work.

Comment: yep, I checked and it worked.  I think it needed `a.*` to get all values in the first table too

Comment: Right, i thought you wanted only seller_id and timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
SELECT a.id as seller_id, a.timestamp as seller_timestamp, a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
FROM sellers a 
LEFT JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN country_types c ON a.country_type_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN language_types d ON a.language_type_id = d.id 
WHERE a.email=?
```

Answer (score 0):

In joins you can't select other columns in this way:

```
SELECT a.id seller_id, a.timestamp seller_timestamp, * FROM sellers a...
```

You need to write required column names.

Comment: I don't want to write out all the column names and would prefer to continue using *.  We get all the values and variables set through this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#102179

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but try alias, for example:

```
a.id AS seller_id
```

and etc.